# PDF appending from a list without manually creating the list

Tags: python, list, pdf, append

I am looking to append a number of pdf files together into a single pdf by creating a list of the pdf filenames, then using the name of that list to bring the pdf files together into one.

I have the following code which returns the pdf filenames in my folder under filenames...

```
import os 
    path = 'C:\\Users\\chinc\\Desktop\\pdf testing'
        filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.pdf')]
        filenames
```

I have also found the following which I have tried to adapt so that I can use the filenames list without having to list them manually.  The reason for doing this is because I will be looking to use this program on a frequent basis where the pdf filenames will change and the number of pdfs I am looking to handle could be up to many hundreds.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for filename in filenames:
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename, 'rb')))
    merger.write('C:\\Users\\chinc\\Desktop\\pdf testing\\123.pdf')
```

Using this code is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-5ae303d6f9cf> in <module>()
      4 
      5 for filename in filenames:
----> 6     merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename, 'rb')))
      7     merger.write('C:\\Users\\chinc\\Desktop\\pdf testing\\123.pdf')

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Given my limited experience in python, I wonder though whether I'm going about this correctly, given all the examples I have seen for appending have called out the filenames explcitly in use.  Is what I'm looking to realistic?

Comment: You aren't opening the file properly. You'll need to open the file for each filename first. I'd also recommend using glob('*.pdf') to locate your files.

Comment: Are you trying to open the file using the statement `file(filename, 'rb')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend checking out the pathlib library as it replaces much of the functionality of the `os` library. If you use pathlib's glob function you will be able to select all of the files in a directory and then use pathlib's open function to open them.

Try this:

```
from pathlib import Path
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

path = Path('C:\\test')
filenames = path.glob('*.pdf')

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(filename.open('rb')))

merger.write('C:\\test\\merged\\merged.pdf')
```

Comment: Mike, this is beautiful coding.  It works perfectly for what I am trying to achieve.  Many thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you liked it!